# AWS - DescribeInstanceTypes for cache instance types

Tags: memory, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, api

I am using DescribeInstanceTypes AWS EC2 API call to obtain the number of CPUs and memory for a given instance type. For example with an input "t3.micro" I get 1 VCPU / 1 GiB of RAM.

But the issue is that we are also using ElastiCache. The instance type there is "cache.t3.micro". The underlaying machine is the same (so cores are the same as t3.micro) however the memory is somehow reserved automatically.

I could hardcode https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/ and use it as a look-up table, but I'd rather avoid that. So my question is how to programatically determine available memory for cache instances. Is there perhaps some other API call (since the former does not understand "cache.t3.micro"). Or perhaps there is a simple formula to calculate memory of "cache.t3.micro" from "t3.micro". For bigger machines the "overhead" seems to be lower (which makes sense) so this is not a constant factor but somehow dependent on available CPUs and/or total memory.

Answer (score 0):

AWS reserves 25% (50% if Redis version is less than  2.8.22, I don't believe this is available now) of memory of an [ElastiCache Redis instance by default](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/available-memory-elasticache-redis-node/). This is governed by the reserved-memory-percent parameter. Unless you are changing this somewhere, its good to assume that the memory available to cache.* instances are the same as the EC2 instances minus the 25% reservation